# php returns empty GET array when trying to fetch MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, http-get

I am trying to make a php REST API for my mobile backend to interact with a MySQL database. I have written out the following code to try and retrieve data from a MySQL query:

```
<?php include "FILE WITH DB_INFO"; ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Testing page</h1>
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL" . mysqli_connect_error();


$database = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_DATABASE);

if (strlen($username_query)) {
    doesUsernameExist($connection, $username_query);
}

doesUsernameExist($connection, $username_query);

$username_query = $_GET['usernameToQuery'];

echo($_GET['usernameToQuery']);


function doesUsernameExist($connection, $username) {
    $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);

    $query = "SELECT username from users WHERE username = ('$u');";


if (!mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
    $response = array("success" => false, "message" => mysqli_error($connection), "sqlerrno" => mysqli_errno($connection), "sqlstate" => mysqli_sqlstate($connection));
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $sth = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    $response = array("success" => true);
    echo json_encode($rows);
}

}
?>
```

This is what the actual request looks like: `http://my_ec2_instance/DoesUsernameExist.php?usernameToQuery=lmao`.
This is sent through POSTMAN.

Because the MySQL database that I am using contains usernames with the value `lmao`, the php function should return an array that is not empty. But the `json_encode($rows);` line returns an empty array `[]`. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: It appears you call `doesUsernameExist()` twice, once inside an `if` statement, once outside.  In both cases, I can't see where you assign a value to `$username_query`.  Am I right?

Comment: @JBH Regardless the echo should output the value. @Mr.Man Check you actually sent a GET request and not POST. Ensure your data is well formatted, etc... you could also check the entire `$_GET` array with a `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: I assigned `$_Get['usernameToQuery']` to `$username_query`. Or did I not do that the correct way?

Comment: :-) Duh.  Thanks, @Geoffrey.  I'd forgotten about that while staring at the script code.  You are correct.

Comment: @Mr.Man What they are trying to say is that you assigned the value of `$_GET['usernameToQuery']` to `$username_query` too late, you should be assigning it near the top of the script... up until you set it, it is pointless to check it as it will be unset/empty/invalid. Check your actually sending the request correctly, use your browser's debug features (Chrome, F12) and check the get variables were actually sent.

Comment: Oh and further, move that `mysqli_connect` into your DB file, no point duplicating it in every script you write. Or better yet use a full framework such as Laravel.

Comment: As a side question, should I make separate .php files in my API for every different kind of request? Like for example should I make one .php file for checking if a username exists, and another for downloading users data; or should I put them into one file? If so, how would I put different requests in one file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you call `doUsernameExiste()` and just before `strlen` with a variable `$username_query`. But you define `$username_query` only after.

You should first do your affectation. Put this after your line with the `mysqli_select_db`

`$username_query = $_GET['usernameToQuery'];`

Comment: Note that the test `echo` after he sets the value should still output the value... this doesn't answer his question.

Comment: You're correct, @Geoffrey.  I forgot he was passing the variable value as a GET.  Oddly, I can't delete this answer.

Comment: @Geoffrey  : the test echo is working yes. But before that he call the function with an undefined variable. So he got not result

Comment: @sheplu Ahh I see, I assumed incorrectly that he wasn't even seeing the `echo` output.